# What does ember-cli use nodewatcher / watchman for?

Tags: ember-cli, watchman

I'm trying to find the basic answer to what specifically ember-cli uses watchman / nodewatcher for, but am having some trouble. I have a feeling that I'm being a bit thickheaded, but would appreciate it if someone here has an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Watchman**

> On OSX and UNIX-like operating systems, we recommend installing Watchman version 3.x, **which provides Ember CLI a more effective way for watching project changes.**
>
> File-watching on OSX is error-prone and Node’s built-in NodeWatcher has trouble observing large trees. Watchman on the other hand, solves these problems and performs well on extremely massive file trees. You can read more about Facebook’s motivations here.

Find out more about `Watchman` in the [Ember CLI User Guide](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman)

`Watchman` allows you to get information about project file changing and to run a rebuild for project ( and optionally to reload your page afterwards )